# Lists and dictionary conversion in python

Tags: python

So in the following program I have comes up with something that isn't working the way I want, and I need help figuring this out.

The first input takes a string

```
"Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309"
```

It first replaces commas with white space, and converts it into list.

```
['Joe', '123-5432', 'Linda', '983-4123', 'Frank', '867-5309']
```

However, I want to convert this list into a dictionary using the first entry as the key, and the second entry as the value. So it would look like this:

```
{'Joe':'123-5432', 'Linda':'983-4123', 'Frank':'867-5309'}
```

This is where I find my problem (within the function). When I call it into the function it broke it up by individual characters, rather than seeing the `.split`s as a whole string, which looks like this...

```
{'J': 'o', 'e': ' ', '1': '2', '3': ' ', '5': '3', ' ': '9', 'i': 'n', 'd': 'a', '8': '6', '-': '4', 'F': 'r', 'a': 'n', 'k': ' ', '7': '-', '0': '9'}
```

Which ya know is funny, but not my target here.

Later in the program, when `Ecall` gets an input, it cross references the list and pulls the phone number from the dictionary. Can you help me build a better comprehension for `Pdict` in the function that does this and not whatever I did?

```
def Convert(FormatInput):
    Pdict = {FormatInput[i]: FormatInput[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(FormatInput), 2)}
    return Pdict

user_input = input()
FormatInput=user_input.replace(",", " ")
Pdict=Convert(FormatInput)

Ecall = (input())
print(Pdict.get(Ecall, 'N/A'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use two different `split` operations instead of doing the `replace` to try to do it in a single `split` (which just makes things more difficult because now you've lost the information of which separator was which).

First split the original string (on whitespace) to produce a list of comma-separated entries:

```
>>> user_input = "Joe,123-5432 Linda,983-4123 Frank,867-5309"
>>> user_input.split()
['Joe,123-5432', 'Linda,983-4123', 'Frank,867-5309']
```

and then split on the commas within each entry so you have a sequence of pairs that you can pass to `dict()`.  You can do the whole thing in one easy line:

```
>>> dict(entry.split(",") for entry in user_input.split())
{'Joe': '123-5432', 'Linda': '983-4123', 'Frank': '867-5309'}
```